# How to select a field named start (a reserved word)

Tags: sql, firebird

I've got a strange problem. A customer named a field in FirebirdSQL `start`. Now I cannot select this field:

```
select t.start from table t
```

Gives me the error: `Invalid token`

Any idea on how I can select this field?

Comment: `select "start" from table` ?

Comment: This doesn't work either. It gives me a constant `start`

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that double quotes escaped reserved words in FB but evidently not.

Comment: This SO answer may be useful: [1800841/using-reserved-word-timestamp-as-a-field-name-firebird-2-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800841/using-reserved-word-timestamp-as-a-field-name-firebird-2-5). Basically, check the lettercase of the column as well.

Comment: @AlexK. Firebird does have quoted identitifier, but lueda is probably using the deprecated legacy dialect 1 instead of dialect 3.

Comment: I gave it a look and it's right. The dialect is in fact 1. My database is historically grown and there is no chance to change the dialect. Anyway... is there any chance with this depracted dialect to use fieldnames which are reserved words?

Comment: @lueda Not as far as I know, but I wouldn't have expected you to be able to create names with reserved words without quoting either (unless those words were reserved afterwards). But seriously: unless you have a very good reason to stick with dialect 1 (and the only one I know is the way it calculates with `NUMERIC/DECIMAL` in multiplication and division), then I'd suggest to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *`start`* is a reserved word in Firebird and therefor needs to be quoted. The quote symbol in Firebird is the double quote. So you need to use:

```
select t."start" from "table" t
```

Note that I quoted *`table`* as well, as it is also a reserved word. Quoting makes the name case sensitive, so you may need to use `"START"` and `"TABLE"`.

In your comments you mention that quoting yields a constant value `'table'`. This means that you are using dialect 1, the deprecated (and legacy) dialect of Firebird. This legacy dialect cannot quote object names, and the double quote is for string literals (next to the SQL standard single quotes). Either your database is a dialect 1 database, or you specified the wrong connection dialect in your connection library.

If your database is actually dialect 3, solving this is as simple as specifying connection dialect 3 (or 0 to auto select based on the database dialect). However if your database is a dialect 1 database you will need to migrate to dialect 3 to be able to solve this.

If this is simply to try things out: make sure you create a dialect 3 database (for most tools this is the default).

### How to determine database dialect

To determine the database dialect, you can use the [gstat tool](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gstat/firebird-gstat.html#gstat-example-header):

```
gstat mydatabase.fdb -header
```

In recent Firebird versions you can also query the `MON$DATABASE` monitoring table. Most query tools also allow you to view the database properties.

### How to migrate from dialect 1 to dialect 3

That is I think too complicated to write down here (and I have never done it myself as it was considered deprecated years ago). However the Interbase 6.0 Getting Started, available from [Firebird: Reference Manuals](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/) (at the end of the page) describes the basic process of migration, and I am sure that there are pages to be found with some googling.

Comment: The problem is the customer uses the old version 1.5 of Firebird. It looks like there is no reserved word `start` in this version. So I installed this version and got no problems with my select. Anyway I marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @lueda Looks like `start` has been reserved since Firebird 2.1, see [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb20x-reswords-added)