# How to combine multiple rows, merging cells with different values across columns and rows using SQL

Tags: sql, database, firebird

Below is the form of data I have right now from a SQL query:

```
ID Name Nationality Institution Degree Result
---------------------------------------------
1  Brian    USA      a           b      c
1  Brian    USA      d           e      f
1  Brian    USA      h           i      j
2  Faye     UK       y           z      x
2  Faye     UK       o           p      q
```

And the data would ideally be sorted as below:

```
 ID Name   Nationality      Background
 -------------------------------------------------
 1  Brian     USA           a,b,c; d,e,f; h,i,j
 2  Faye      UK            y,z,x; o,p,q
```

I'm a SQL beginner and I'd very much appreciate any help with this.

Below is my current SQL query:

```
select 
    table1.id,
    table1.lastname,
    table1.firstname,
    table1.group,
    table2.institution,
    table2.degree,
    table2.result,
from 
    table1
inner join 
    table2 on (table1.id = table2.id)
where 
    ((table1.startyear = '2017')
     and (table1.group = 'A'))
```

Comment: MySql <> MS Access <> MS SQL Server

Comment: mySQL uses and `Group_Concat()` for this, SQL server would use `String_Agg()` if 2017 or `Stuff and FORXML path`, I don't think msaccess handles this easily  So each solution is dependent on the specific database.  What database platform are you really using?  concat() would be used to combine the data within the rows, group_concat() for XML path or string_Agg for combining rows.  This type of has been answered several times on SO already.  We just need to know what RDBMS so we can link the appropriate answer.

Comment: I've edited your post to remove conflicting tags. Please tag ONLY the DBMS you are using as the responses will be DBMS specific

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016435/xqbert

Comment: @aaron yep that's me :P

Comment: @xQbert IBExpert is the platform I'm using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635451/firebird-2-5-equivalent-function-to-stuff-in-sql-group-concat-in-mysql-list  Looks like LIST() would work.  seems to be equlivant to group_Concat()

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for the response...where should I add that in? thankss

Comment: @aaron see below Untested Answer.  What version of firebird  as https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-aggrfunc-list.html indicates `list()` was added in 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
Select Id, [Name], Nationality, 
    Background = Stuff((Select '; '+Institution+','+Degree+','+Result from #table1 where id = t.Id for xml path('')),1,2,'')
 from #table1 t
 Group by Id, [Name], Nationality
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there appears to be an error with the Background line

Comment: It works only on SQL Server... Never mind if you are using different dbms

Answer (score 0):

So using `list()` and the `||` string concat in Firebird ( IBExpert ) gives us:

UNTESTED:  `List()` [Doc](https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-aggrfunc-list.html) requires 2.1 version or greater.
A prior [SO answer using `List()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635451/firebird-2-5-equivalent-function-to-stuff-in-sql-group-concat-in-mysql-list)

Note `Group` is on the [reserved words list](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-reskeywords-full-reswords.html); so you may have to escape it using `"` in [firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800841/using-reserved-word-timestamp-as-a-field-name-firebird-2-5)

```
SELECT table1.id
     , table1.lastname
     , table1.firstname
     , table1."group"
     , List(table2.institution ||','||
            table2.degree      ||','||
            table2.result,';') as Background
FROM table1
INNER JOIN  table2 
   ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.startyear = '2017'
  AND table1."group" = 'A'
GROUP BY table1.id
       , table1.lastname
       , table1.firstname
       , table1."group"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Apart from the last line, I got an error message from it but when I removed it the query seemed to have worked

Comment: just need to put group in quotes (fixed) (I missed that one)

Comment: I still get the error message: can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg not found.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 41, column 22.
"group".

Comment: table1 has a field called group right?  or did you remove group from the select (if so removing it from group by makes sense)

Comment: Ah right, yeah not exactly as i simplified the fields but I get it now, my mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @aaron if this solves your question please accept the answer otherwise the question remains open and people think it's unresolved.